# WordPress says media isn't uploaded, but it is?

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

In WordPress, I'm uploading media and getting the message:

> The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2016/06.

Yet, the file *is* in that location, it uploads every time I try.

Along with the error message, the uploaded file doesn't appear in media  selections - it's like WordPress can't read it and is giving me the wrong error message.

What could be going on here?

Comment: If you could share the code responsible for uploading and serving that message, then we might be able to see what's happening.

Comment: Please share you code as well for better understanding ..

Comment: Please also confirm if the uploaded files were in fact a valid file - size is greater than 0 byte and readable.

Comment: Check your permissions of the `uploads` folder in your `wp-content` folder. And owner and group owner as well...

Comment: this link will help you. http://2surge.com/how-to-fix-the-uploaded-file-could-not-be-moved-to-wp-content-error-message/

Comment: Permissions and group owner all look good - I changed to 777 to be doubly sure. The file upload is there. WordPress doesn't recognize that it happened though.

Comment: Since changing permissions to 777 didn't work, I changed permissions + group owner back to copy everything on a working install on the same server. Still doesn't work - could this be something in WordPress code or db interfering?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permissions of both the 'wp-content' and 'uploads' folders to 777 (maybe currently they are set to chmod 775).

It is possible that at the moment you have permissions only for one of these folders and, because uploading an image to wordpress is a whole process, some part of it may encounter an error, but other may still be successful.

Every image can be seen in the database in the table 'wp_posts' with 'post_type' attachment, as well as in the 'wp_postmeta' table where two inserts are made with meta_keys '_wp_attached_file' and '_wp_attachment_metadata'. If, by any chance, wordpress cannot get the data needed to generate metadata for the image, this may be the cause for you not to be able to see the picture in the admin panel. So you can also check if everything is ok with the information in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It was a server issue, my server was out of space. The files looked like they'd uploaded correctly, the filename was created, but the file wasn't actually there.